# Bash run a program / script and read output and act accordingly

Tags: bash

Lets say you run a static installing script and you plan to do it over lot's of machines at the same time automatically. Currently the closest I can make it is cluster ssh, but it requires me to do the inputs.

How can I read the output and do an action on them since I know what it will ask for so I can predict what it should respond.

Comment: `output=$(ssh -q TARGET_HOST "COMMAND")`

Comment: What have you tried so far? Then we can point you in the right direction.

Comment: @RobertSeaman I have not tried anything as I'm not sure if it's even possible. And there are more than 1 output, etc it will do some stuff, then ask for which folder to install to, then do some stuff and ask something else and so on.

Comment: Any reason you're not just using something like Ansible or Puppet Bolt?

Comment: @AlexHarvey Not really no. I do use puppet already. Do you know if this can be done from bolt?

Comment: Yes, Bolt and Ansible are designed specifically for this kind of task.

Comment: Have you already had a look at expect? It runs a command and can perform actions according to what the command prints. (Anyway ansible seems the right tool for handling lot of machines).

Comment: @AlexHarvey I will take a look, nobody here has any experience with it.

Comment: @MaxP I have not heard about that no, I will look at it.

Comment: Expect looks really good for this, I will look at bolt too tho to see if it may be better since I already have a puppet environment.